# Can I use the Pokebank without a Pokemon game?

Tags: pokemon-bank

I don't have my old Pokemon X game any more but I would still like to access the Pokemon Bank, is this possible?

Comment: Get another copy of Pokemon X?

Answer (score 5):

Do you have any other Pokemon games? If not, you will not be able to access PokeBank as it ***REQUIRES*** a game to be used, otherwise you will not be able to transfer. Any of these games are compatible:

- **Generation 6**:

  - Pokemon X and Y
  - Pokemon Omega Ruby and Alpha Sapphire
- **Generation 7**:

  - Pokemon Sun and Moon
  - Pokemon Ultra Sun and Ultra Moon

Answer (score -1):

If your session got disconnected while you were using a game you no longer have, you should call nintendo support.  I had this problem and they were able to fix it for me over the phone.